# How to see another nodes applications on Websphere console?

Tags: java, server, websphere

I have a Websphere profile which has 2 nodes. I can login into the

```
https://localhost:9044/ibm/console/
```

and click on the **Application Server**, I can only see the `Node02` applications as the header is

```
Cell=Node02Cell, Profile=AppSrv02.
```

Actually in the

```
c:/IBM/Websphere/profile/,
```

there are 2 servers `AppSrv01` and `AppSrv02`, both are startup. May I know how to see `Node01Cell` server and applications?

Comment: Actually I communicated with previous guy who deploy the app server. He told me: https ://localhost:9043/ibm/console is set to access the server node 1, https ://localhost:9044/ibm/console is set to access the server node 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question that the two servers are in different sub directories of the one quoted. Assuming you are using the WAS base product there is no way to see both profiles in single admin console at once. You can use WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment and federate two different profiles into the same cell at which point you could see both of the servers. With base you can use the admin agent to manage two profiles on the same machine, but you would manage each profile individually.

Comment: @Gas, Thanks for helping me. Actually when I login from a remote pc to [http://server-machine:9043/ibm/console](http://server-machinename:9043/ibm/console), I can see and manage node1 applications. But if I login from the the server local to [http://localhost:9043/ibm/console](http://server-machinename:9043/ibm/console), I can see node2 applications. This is so strange!

Comment: @WangYufan This is rather not possible. But check the ports, maybe you use 9043 for one and 9044 for the second.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alasdair answer, in case of WAS base, if you want to manage all servers on the same host you can use Admin Agent profile. You would need to create new profile and register your profiles in the admin agent.
Then you will be able to manage both servers via single console, selecting during login, which server you want to manage.

For details see [Setting up the administrative agent environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tagt_adminagent_setup.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you installed two stand-alone application server profiles with individual console.  To create a clustered or multiple node setup, you will need to install a Deployment Manager profile as your main console then add two nodes to be federated by the Deployment Manger.

See: [Installing WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRMWJ_6.0.0.2/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0.0.2/installing/tsk/tsk_ic_ins_was_clusterinstall.htm)